# why only three word is write on the memory ? assembly language

Tags: assembly, video-memory

```
.model small

.stack 200h

.data   

string1 db 'wahab $'

.code

main proc 

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,0b800h 

    mov es,ax  

    mov ax,offset string1 
    mov si,ax 
    mov di,0

    l1:

    mov ax,[si]

    mov es:[di],ax 
    inc si
    inc di

    cmp ax,'$'
    jne l1           

    main endp
```

---

only three character is display on the screen or video memory ?

Comment: The characters in your string are one **byte** each. The size of the `ax` register is one **word** (2 bytes). Use a register of the appropriate size, like `al`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video memory is word-aligned. Even byte is a characted to display, odd byte is color attribute. Thus, when you do `mov [es:di], ax` to video memory segment, `AL` holds a character to be displayed, and `AH` - color of that character.

```
l1:

mov al,[si]

mov es:[di],al 
inc si
add di, 2

cmp al,'$'
jne l1
```